# There is a saying like

Tags: word-usage

> There is a saying like "Eat like a king for breakfast, a queen for lunch and a pauper for dinner".

I use first “ like” in sentence above to say there is a such saying but I couldn’t remember it very well. When I use “that” it sounds like I am sure that this is the saying . But I am not sure İf the saying is in this way or not . This is why I use “like”. Can I use “like” in this way?

Comment: I assume you mean the first like, e.g. "a saying like"? and not the second like, "eat like ..."

Comment: Yes I mean first like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use like that way. You could (maybe even should) expand it to be "There is a saying **that goes something** like ..." but the shortened version is fine, especially when speaking.